# Understanding uncertainty of thoughts and the mind

Tags: reference-request, vipassana, anatman, guidance

It's quite easy to see the changing behaviour of the things we see, hear and feel.

1. Appearence between a child and an old man.
2. Good smell and bad smell
3. Having a wound and not

Those things are quite easy to see. But it is hard to see the changing behaviour of mind and thoughts.

I'm aware of

1. I may angry now. But I will be grateful in next five minutes. (Changing thoughts). (But I'm also getting repitative thoughts)
2. I have different prespective than in my childhood.
3. Knowledge that I have is changing.
4. If cut down the body into pieces, we can not find any "I"
5. I and I in the previous life shoud be totaly different (Can see this clearly if I was an animal.)

Even thoughts are changing, It feels like source of it remains unchanged. How to understand this clearly? What are the practises that I should do? What meditation practises help to understand this?

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the phenomena of the monkey-like mind, which changes more quickly than the body.

From [SN 12.61](https://suttacentral.net/sn12.61/en/bodhi):

> “It would be better, bhikkhus, for the uninstructed worldling to take
> as self this body composed of the four great elements rather than the
> mind. For what reason? Because this body composed of the four great
> elements is seen standing for one year, for two years, for three,
> four, five, or ten years, for twenty, thirty, forty, or fifty years,
> for a hundred years, or even longer. But that which is called ‘mind’
> and ‘mentality’ and ‘consciousness’ arises as one thing and ceases as
> another by day and by night. Just as a monkey roaming through a forest
> grabs hold of one branch, lets that go and grabs another, then lets
> that go and grabs still another, so too that which is called ‘mind’
> and ‘mentality’ and ‘consciousness’ arises as one thing and ceases as
> another by day and by night.
>
> “Therein, bhikkhus, the instructed noble disciple attends closely and
> carefully to dependent origination itself thus: ‘When this exists,
> that comes to be; with the arising of this, that arises. When this
> does not exist, that does not come to be; with the cessation of this,
> that ceases. That is, with ignorance as condition, volitional
> formations come to be; with volitional formations as condition,
> consciousness…. Such is the origin of this whole mass of suffering.
> But with the remainderless fading away and cessation of ignorance
> comes cessation of volitional formations; with the cessation of
> volitional formations, cessation of consciousness…. Such is the
> cessation of this whole mass of suffering.

OP wrote:

> Even thoughts are changing, It feels like source of it remains
> unchanged. How to understand this clearly? What are the practises that
> I should do? What meditation practises help to understand this?

Please try the meditation practice taught by [Ven. Yuttadhammo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuttadhammo_Bhikkhu) in his booklet "[How To Meditate](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/)" and also taught in this [video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL603BD0B03E12F5A1).

I quote from Chapter One of "[How To Meditate](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/)":

> The basic technique of meditation that we use to facilitate this
> change is the creation of clear awareness. In meditation, we try to
> create a clear awareness of every experience as it occurs. Without
> meditating, we tend to immediately judge and react to our experiences
> as “good”, “bad”, “me”, “mine”, etc., which in turn gives rise to
> stress, suffering, and mental sickness. By creating a clear thought
> about the object, we replace these sort of judgements with a simple
> recognition of the object as it is.